# Change the dimension of a custom dialog when orientation changes

Tags: android

How to change the dimension of Dialog in android when orientation changes.

**code in onCreate**

```
static final float[] DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE = {20, 60};
static final float[] DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT = {40, 60};

final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int orientation = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

float[] dimensions =
                (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                        ? DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE : DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT;
                 addContentView(mContent, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    display.getWidth() - ((int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f)),
                    display.getHeight() - ((int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f))));
```

**I want to do the same when the orientation change. Please help**

Answer (score 1):

just check this out it a custom code to set up dialog height according to oriebtation : it works for me by implementing this my dialog become flexible ...i m using this in tablet ..

```
WindowManager winMan = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            int height = winMan.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            int width=winMan.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            if(height>width){

                if(DeviceType.getDeviceType(context)==Device.NEXUS7){
                dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700,1100));
                }else if (DeviceType.getDeviceType(context)==Device.GALAXYTAB2){
                    dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(580,900));
                }else if(DeviceType.getDeviceType(context)==Device.GALAXY10){
                    dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700,1100));
                }


            else{
                if(DeviceType.getDeviceType(context)==Device.NEXUS7){
                    dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700,700));
                }else if (DeviceType.getDeviceType(context)==Device.GALAXYTAB2){
                    dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700,500));
                    System.out.println("galaxy tab 2 landescape");
                }else if(DeviceType.getDeviceType(context)==Device.GALAXY10){
                dialoglayout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(700,700));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a method init and put stuff you want to happen during onCreate and on orientation changes.

First you should add this to your activity xml

`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`

Then implement the method

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE = {20, 60};
    static final float[] DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT = {40, 60};

    final float scale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    float[] dimensions =
                (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
                        ? DIMENSIONS_DIFF_LANDSCAPE : DIMENSIONS_DIFF_PORTRAIT;
                 addContentView(mContent, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    display.getWidth() - ((int) (dimensions[0] * scale + 0.5f)),
                    display.getHeight() - ((int) (dimensions[1] * scale + 0.5f))));
}
```

But you should still do that on onCreate too.